# Difference between PubSub and Methods

Tags: methods, meteor, publish-subscribe

What is the difference between **PubSub** and **Methods** in Meteor?!

Can I put Methods in Server folder like Publishs?

To me seen like the same, but Methods is more reactive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are two different sides of the same coin.  Here's a drawing of the data lifecycle in meteor:

[image: Meteor Data Lifecycle]

- [**Publish**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) - Which data is sent from the *server*
- [**Subscribe**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe) -  Which data the *client* requests publications for
- [**Methods**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) - How to manipulate data from the client on the server

  - **Note** - this will typically be run on both on the client and the server.  The client will make a prediction as to what the server will do so it can update right away.  Then *latency compensation* will kick in when the method is run on the server and the canonical decision is made.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the difference between PubSub and Methods in Meteor?!

Publications are reactive and they provide a cursor. Subscription gets you the matching publication on clientside in a minimongo database. On the other hand, methods must be called instead of subscribed and they are mainly designed to execute server side tasks that you don't want to handle client side for many possible reasons.

More details here for publications: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/

And here for methods:
http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/methods/

> Can I put Methods in Server folder like Publishs?

Yes you can and you should. For example, put them into `server\methods`

> To me seen like the same, but Methods is more reactive.

This is the exact contrary. They are not the same, even if you can achieve similar results with both. Methods are by design not reactive, and pub/sub are.